# Set NFC mode, speed and other options through Qt (under linux)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, nfc, nfc-p2p

I have an Android app (not written in Qt) and a Linux application (written in Qt). They shall communicate via NFC with each other. The Linux box has an ACR122 smart card reader.

My plan is to use the Linux side as the initiator and the Android app as the target of the NFC communication. Moreover, I plan to use the peer-to-peer mode of NFC in the passive variant. I.e. the Linux box actively powers the HF field all the time, NFCIP-1 is used on the transport layer, on top of that LLCP and finally NDEF messages are exchanged.

If I understand the specs correctly, the initiator dictates the operation mode (424 kb/s, p2p-mode, passive). But I do not find any way how to set the operation mode through the Qt library.

What am I missing?

*Some more background info*

My initial idea was to (only) use libnfc for the Linux application as the application is only a CLI daemon and so Qt is actually not a real requirement. However, then I found out that libnfc is really low level. It does not provide an interface for the LLCP level nor NDEF data structures. I also found libllcp from nfc-tools and libndef (which is based on Qt core) but both seem to lack any documentation. Finally, I ended up with the idea to use Qt for the Linux application.

Comment: Youre missing developers sdk for your device. There must be some sort of library. You download it, include it into your qt project and call some functions like myDevise.setWhateverINeed(value).

Comment: If C++ is not a requirement you could try Python with https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nfcpy. There are also Python bindings for QT.